# How to use strings to find and update an object

Tags: javascript, json

In javascript, I'm loading an json object, and trying to update values within it. Elements in html have ids that match their path, such that the "values.one" element in this:

> {"values":{"one":"val1","two":"val2"},"OtherStuff":"whatever"}

would be related to this element:

```
<input id="values_one" type="text">val1</div>
```

When this element loses focus, I want to grab the value of "#values_one" (using jQuery) and set use whatever value is there into my json object. I've figured out how to get the value from the existing json object (see my horrid code below), but I end up with nothing but the value, so setting it doesn't affect the json object. Any suggestions on how I can do this (assuming that I don't know whether the element that lost focus was "values_one", "values_two", or any other element that might map to the json object)?

Here's the code that I have at this point (that isn't working), but happy to scrap it for something that actually works:

> ```
> var saveEdit = function() {
>   var data = getJson();
>   pathElements = $(this).attr('id').split('_'); 
>   length = pathElements.length;
>   var path = data[pathElements[0]];
>   index = 1;
>   while (index < length) {
>       path = path[pathElements[index]];
>       length -= 1;
>   }
>   path = $(this).text(); //resets "path", but not data.values.one
>   $(this).unbind();
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop one shorter than the length, so that you get the element that contains the property that matches the last identifier:

```
var path = data;
for (index = 0; index < length - 1; index++) {
  path = path[pathElements[index]];
}
path[pathElements[length - 1]] = $(this).text();
```

Comment: I see what you're saying! data['values'] is still an object, but once I get data['values']['one'], all I have is the value (in other words, a string). Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, there's no such thing as a "JSON Object". Yes, I'm being pedantic, but you should either have a "JSON String", or a "Javascript Object".

It looks like you're trying to modify a *JSON string* via events, instead of just having the object itself available to reference and modify. Why bother keeping it in a string? When you're ready to export the data (perhaps saving to a db), then just `stringify();` the object and be on your way.

Take a look at the following jsFiddle for a working implementation that you can build off of: http://jsfiddle.net/julianlam/WRZPF/

Comment: The json string (you're right - I should use the correct term) is loaded as a hidden element. Basically, I'm trying to update that string and replace the elements value. I'm loading the string using jQuery.parseJSON, which I assumed would return an object, not just the string (but I could be wrong)